# Packing polygons without intersection and empty places

Tags: leaflet, algorithm, maps, convex-hull, concave-hull

How can I pack polygons without empty places and intersections?
Please tell me everything that might help me (API, algorithms, etc.)

I'm using:

- USPS API to get carrier routes.
- dbscan.js to generate clusters from points.
- hull.js to generate polygons.
- leaflet to show map

---

Example (I have):

[image]

---

Example (I need):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a convex hull over a set of points with the same attributes, create a Voronoi tesselation of all points, then merge the Voronoi polygons of those points with the same attributes.

There are lots of ways to process the information you may have, and what I just said is one idea on how to do it. Voronoi + merge might create multipolygons, which might not be what you want.